# new validation webhook feature inside Twilio Collect action

Tags: twilio

I saw that Twilio added a new feature when using the Collect action, which allows one to validate the user answer by means of a web hook. Here's the link: https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect

I'm wondering if this is already part of the framework or not. I've tried small examples, and also the long sample they have in the documentation (using my own webhooks of course), and the validation web hook is not being triggered, or called at all.

as an example I have the following:

```
{"actions": [
    {
        "collect": {
            "name": "date_questions",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "question": "What date?",
                    "name": "date",
                    "type": "Twilio.DATE",
                    "validate": {
                        "on_failure": {
                            "messages": [
                                {
                                    "say": "Sorry, that's not a valid date."
                                },
                                {
                                    "say": "Hmm, I'm not understanding what you're saying"
                                }
                            ],
                            "repeat_question": true
                        },
                        "webhook": {
                            "method": "POST",
                            "url": "https://my_validation_wh"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "on_complete": {
                "redirect": "https://my_on_complete_wh"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: Your JSON looks correct.
How are you checking if your webhook is being called or not ?
If you are using ngrok, make sure the url is updated to the latest ngrok tunnel url. 
Also check if response from your webhook is inline with this : https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#collect-validate-webhook